# How do you Snip & Sketch while Admin elevated software is in focus?

Tags: windows-10

If I open a program that requires Administrative Rights to function, like Minitool Partition Wizard Free for example, the Print Screen button will not open Snip & Sketch for screenshotting unless I have the Partition Wizard program not in focus. This means I can not get screenshots of the contents of the menu bar items.

For example I open the program and click File, if I press Print Screen nothing happens but if I place focus on the Taskbar (which closes the File menu) and press Print Screen the Snip & Sketch program will open and allow me to take a screenshot that can include the elevated program.

How do I resolve this bizarre phenomena? Why does a programs level of elevation affect another programs ability to take a snapshot of the display contents...

Comment: Press Win+Print Screen keys.

Comment: Win+PrtScn doesn't not function the same as just PrtScn once `Settings > Ease of Access > Keyboard > "Use PrtScn button to open screen snipping"` is enabled. I believe the original question is asking for a way to elevate this functionality, where when you press PrtScn it launches Windows 10's "Snip & Sketch" tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Win + Shift + S` works.

`PrtScr` may not work on elevated processes. `Win+PrtScr` do not provide the same functionalities as Snip & Sketch.

Comment: This issue has been driving me crazy for over a year now and this is the best solution I've found thus far, though it's not as preferred as elevating the PrtScn shortcut somehow.

Comment: As ttimasdf pointed out, Win+Shift+S works. You can also simply remove focus from the administrative program to engage in snipping & sketching (click an empty portion of the Task Bar for example).

Also sorry for the very late response, I had completely forgotten about this!